# Corda - Specifying an app name for a mock network

Tags: corda

If I call `flowSession.getCounterpartyFlowInfo()` from a unit test using `MockNetwork`, it returns `FlowInfo(flowVersion=1, appName=<unknown>)`

Here is my current `MockNetwork` configuration:

```
network = MockNetwork(
    MockNetworkParameters(
        cordappsForAllNodes = listOf(
            TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.example.contract"),
            TestCordapp.findCordapp("com.example.workflow")
        ),
        networkParameters = testNetworkParameters(
            minimumPlatformVersion = 5
        )
    )
)
```

Is there a way to specify the `appName` of an application running in a mock network?

Comment: Just a note for anyone at R3 that answers this to let Matthew know as he's on slack as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a configuration for that. The appName is derived from the jar file name by removing the '.jar' extension.

For the MockNode, the packages are scanned and classes are loaded.

Here is how it's derived:

```
val Class<out FlowLogic<*>>.appName: String
get() {
    val jarFile = location.toPath()
    return if (jarFile.isRegularFile() && jarFile.toString().endsWith(".jar")) {
        jarFile.fileName.toString().removeSuffix(".jar")
    } else {
        "<unknown>"
    }
}
```